# Problems installing mysql-workbench 17.04

Tags: xubuntu, 17.04, mysql-workbench

I'm having problems installing mysql-workbench on my Xubuntu 17.04.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: python-paramiko but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Attempt #1:**

I've tried to install the apt repo from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/, but no luck

**Attempt #2:**

Download the .deb package, no luck.

**Attempt #3:**

`sudo apt install -f`
No luck

**Attempt #4:**

`pip install paramiko`
It did install, but mysql-workbench didn't after that.

I'm lost, any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)